# Find the points with the steepest slope python

Tags: python

I have a list of float points such as `[x1,x2,x3,x4,....xn]` that are plotted as a line graph. I would like to find the set of points where the slope is the steepest.

Right now, Im calculating the difference between a set of points in a loop and using the `max()` function to determine the maximum point.

Any other elegant way of doing this?

Comment: if your points are equally spaced (or assumed to be) your method is as elegant as it can get. The question is how elegant your code is.

Comment: Presently, im doing it as follows
`for i in range(len(list)):
slope.append(list[i] - list[i+1])
print(slope.index(max(slope)))` where slope is the list of the differences and list is the original list of float points

Comment: Turning your list into a numpy array and using `numpy.diff` may feel more elegant. (E.g., the code would be something ike `steepest = np.argmax(np.diff(np.array(my_list)))`.

Comment: @Mechanic your code does not run btw. You get an index error.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis sorry. The first line should be `for i in range(len(list)-1)`. forgot to add -1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `points` is the list of your values, you can calculate the differences in a single line using:

```
max_slope = max([x - z for x, z in zip(points[:-1], points[1:])])
```

But what you gain in compactness, you probably lose in readability.

What happens in this list comprehension is the following:

- Two lists are created based on the original one, namely `points[:-1]` & `points[1:]`. `Points[:-1]` starts from the beginning of the original list and goes to the second to last item (inclusive). `Points[1:]` starts from the second item and goes all the way to the last item (inclusive again.)

Example

```
example_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ex_a = example_list[:-1]  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
ex_b = example_list[1:]   # [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

- Then you zip the two lists creating an object from which you can draw x, z pairs to calculate your differences. Note that `zip` does not create a list in Python 3 so you need to pass it's return value to the `list` argument.

Like:

```
example_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ex_a = example_list[:-1]  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
ex_b = example_list[1:]   # [2, 3, 4, 5]
print(list(zip(ex_a, ex_b)))  # [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
```

- Finally, you calculate the differences using the created pairs, store the results in a list and get the maximum value.

If the location of the max slope is also interesting you can get the index from the created list by using the `.index()` method. In that case, though, it would probably be better to save the list created by the comprehension and not just use it.

Answer (score 4):

`Numpy` has a number of tools for working with arrays. For example, you could:

```
import numpy as np

xx = np.array([x1, x2, x3, x4, ...])  # your list of values goes in there
print(np.argmax(xx[:-1] - xx[1:]))  # for all python versions
```

Comment: You don't need numpy to get rid of the for loop but this solution is elegant too.